# How do I create a GZIP bundle in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have thousands of files that I want to GZIP together to make sending them more efficient. I used MergeContent, but that creates **zip** files, not **GZIP**. The system on the other side is only looking for GZIP. I can use CompressContent to create a single GZIP file, but that's not efficient for sending across the network. Also I need to preserve headers on the individual files which is why I wanted to use MergeContent.

I could write the files to disk as flowfile packages, run a script, pick up the result, then send it, but I would think I can do that in NiFi without writing to disk.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing compression with archiving.

Tar or Zip is method of archiving 1 or more input files into a single output file. E.g. file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt are separate files that are archived into files.tar. When you unpack the archive, you get all 3 files back as they were. An archive is not necessarily compressed.

GZIP is a method of compression, with the goal of reducing the size of the file. It takes 1 input, compresses it, and gives 1 output. E.g. You input file1.txt which is 100Kb, you compress it, you get file1.txt.gz which is 3Kb.

MergeContent is *merging*, thus is can produce archives like ZIP and TAR. It is *not* compressing.

CompressContent is *compressing*, thus it can produce compressed files like GZIP. It is *not* merging.

If you want to combine many files into a *compressed archive* like a `tar.gz` then you can use MergeContent (tar) > CompressContent (gzip). This will first archive all of the input FlowFiles into a `tar` file, and then GZIP compress the `tar` into a `tar.gz`.

See this answer for more detail on compression vs archiving: [Difference between archiving and compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614239/difference-between-archiving-and-compression)

(Note: MergeContent has an optional Compression flag when using it to create ZIPs, so in that one specific use-case it can also apply some compression to the archive, but it is **only** for `zip`)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explaination! 

I think I got confused because one of my colleagues was very vague. I tried MergeContent (using Binary Concatenation and a high number for maximum entries), then CompressContent to create a GZIP file. That seems to be what I need.